# Drupal: "Schema module" installed and new error in status report

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've installed schema module to import database entries into my drupal CCK fields. Now in the statuus report I get the following error message. Can I just ignore, or is something serious I should fix ?

```
Database schema
Inconsistent The
Schema comparison report shows:
42 modules with matching tables
41 extra tables
2 warnings
3 module with mis-matching tables
```

More precisely:

```
Mismatch (4)
Tables for which the schema and database are different.

user
users

timezone_name: unexpected column in database

image_fupload
fupload_previewlist

column uid - difference on: length
declared: array('description' => t('TODO: please describe this field!'), 'type' => 'int', 'length' => '10', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => 0)
actual: array('description' => t('TODO: please describe this field!'), 'type' => 'int', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => 0)
column nid - difference on: length
declared: array('description' => t('TODO: please describe this field!'), 'type' => 'int', 'length' => '10', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => 0)
actual: array('description' => t('TODO: please describe this field!'), 'type' => 'int', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => 0)
column fid - differences on: not null, length
declared: array('description' => t('TODO: please describe this field!'), 'type' => 'int', 'length' => '11', 'not null' => FALSE, 'default' => 0)
actual: array('description' => t('TODO: please describe this field!'), 'type' => 'int', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => 0)
column created - difference on: length
declared: array('description' => t('TODO: please describe this field!'), 'type' => 'int', 'length' => '11', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => 0)
actual: array('description' => t('TODO: please describe this field!'), 'type' => 'int', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

Make sure that you've run update.php and that all database changes by modules are up to date.

You can sometimes run into trouble with a staging and live site if you copy databases or modules between them and fail to keep database changes in sync. Not much you can do there but manually rectify.

If your site is fully updated and there are no dev/staging/live discrepancies then it's unlikely that there's anything you should do other than report the issue to the module developer.